# how to put values from wordpress postmeta table into a foreach loop

Tags: wordpress

I'm trying to put all the values from a postmeta key into a foreach loop ,

I've tried get_post_ meta and get_post_custom but these only seem to work based on a post Id .

Also tried get_post_custom_values but this again only seems to return the current post..?

I just want all the values from a certain meta_key . I'm trying to populate a form dropdown list with the values...?

Any ideas...

This is what i now have;

```
$results = $wpdb->get_results( "SELECT $wpdb->postmeta.meta_value WHERE $wpdb- >
postmeta.meta_key = 'geo_short_address'" );
$options = array();
foreach ($results as $result) {
$options[$result->meta_value] = ucwords( $meta_value );
```

}

```
?>
             </select> 
        <select name="country" id="country">
        <option value="selected">Select a location</option>
        <?php




        foreach ($options as $key => $value) {
            ?>
        <?php $retaincount = $value  ?>
                       <option <?php if ($_GET['country'] == $retaincount ) { ?
         >selected="<?php echo $value; ?>" <?php }; ?>value="<?php echo $value ?>">
         <?  php echo $value?></option>


            <?php

    }
    ?>
             </select> 
    <p>
    <input type="submit" value="<?php _e('Filter', 'appthemes'); ?>"
            class="submit" />
    <input type="hidden" name="action" value="Filter" />

    </p>
    <div class="clear"></div>
        </form>
        <?php endif;



        }

        Thanks
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm pretty sure that you will need a custom MySQL query for that.

Here is something that should work:

```
global $wpdb;

$results = $wpdb->get_results( "SELECT $wpdb->postmeta.meta_value FROM $wpdb->postmeta WHERE 1=1 AND $wpdb->postmeta.meta_key = 'geo_short_address'" );
$options = array();
foreach ($results as $result) {
    $options[$result->meta_value] = ucwords( $result->meta_value );
}

echo '<select class="field" name="country">';
foreach ($options as $key => $value) {
    echo "<option value='$key'" . ( $_GET['country'] == $value ? " selected='selected'" : "" ) . ">$value</option>";
}
'</select>';
```

Just replace `'custom_key'` with your custom field name and that should give you all values for that custom field.

I can't test the code right now, so feel free to tell me if it's not working.

Comment: many thanks for your help - I have edited my question to reflect your answer - its sill not populating can you spot where i may have gone wrong...? thanks

Comment: I had a small error in my code, but I think that's not the reason. Any way change `ucwords( $meta_value )` to `ucwords( $result->meta_value )`. Then do a `var_dump( $results, $options )` after the closing `}` of the `foreach ($results as $result)` loop and add that as well. I'm not sure whether the query is not getting the results, or it's something else.

Comment: added this foreach ($results as $result) {
    $options[$result->meta_value] = ucwords( $result->meta_value );
}
echo var_dump( $results, $options ) but nothing returning ?

Comment: getting Null NULL for result and options ..?

Comment: sorry var_dump array empty for both

Comment: I had an error in my MySQL query - forgot the `FROM ...` part :) I've now tested it and it's working properly. You should use my code, or modify yours, because what gets sent to the server is the `value='$key'` and you're checking if `$_GET['country'] == $value`, which is the label of the option.